# How do I give space between the two bar charts

Tags: bar-chart

I want to plot two bar plots with more space next to each other (now the yaxis label overlaps on first figure). Also I want to add x axis label and a caption for each figure. Can anyone help me to solve the problem?
Code:

```
 \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1},width=12cm,height=8cm]
        \nextgroupplot[
            %legend style={at={(mygroup.south)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            symbolic x coords={Precision,Recall,F1-Score,Accuracy},
            major tick length=0cm,
            xtick=data,
            ymin=50.0,
            ylabel = {y},
            xlabel = {x},
            enlarge x limits=0.2,
            enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.2},
            nodes near coords,
            ybar,
            every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
            bar width = 8pt,
        ]

        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,86.6) (Recall,86.0) (F1-Score,86.3) (Accuracy,98.4)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,87.6) (Recall,86.2) (F1-Score,86.5) (Accuracy,97.5)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,85.9) (Recall,86.3) (F1-Score,86.1) (Accuracy,98.6)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,87.1) (Recall,86.8) (F1-Score,87.0) (Accuracy,99.2)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,85.5) (Recall,82.8) (F1-Score,83.7) (Accuracy,97.4)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,77.9) (Recall,77.7) (F1-Score,75.9) (Accuracy,87.8)};
        %\legend{KNN,Neural Networks,Decision Tree,Random Forest,SVM,Naive Bayes}

        \nextgroupplot[
            legend style={at={(-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/group/horizontal sep}/2,-0.1)},
                    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            symbolic x coords={Precision,Recall,F1-Score,Accuracy},
            major tick length=0cm,
            xtick=data,
            ymin=50.0,
            ylabel = {y},
            enlarge x limits=0.2,
            enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.2},
            nodes near coords,
            ybar,
            every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
            bar width = 8pt,
        ]

        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,86.6) (Recall,86.0) (F1-Score,86.3) (Accuracy,98.4)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,87.6) (Recall,86.2) (F1-Score,86.5) (Accuracy,97.5)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,85.9) (Recall,86.3) (F1-Score,86.1) (Accuracy,98.6)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,87.1) (Recall,86.8) (F1-Score,87.0) (Accuracy,99.2)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,85.5) (Recall,82.8) (F1-Score,83.7) (Accuracy,97.4)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,77.9) (Recall,77.7) (F1-Score,75.9) (Accuracy,87.8)};
        



        \legend{KNN,Neural Networks,Decision Tree,Random Forest,SVM,Naive Bayes}
    \end{groupplot}
    
    
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To get more space between the two bar charts you can use in the `groupplot` environment: `group/horizontal sep=Xcm` (initially 1cm).

Comment: Where do you want to place the x axis label?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to have a look at the [manual of pgfplots](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) (5.8 Grouping plots). The passages in italics are taken directly from the manual.

**1. Space**

With

- `group/horizontal sep=<dimension>`
- `group/vertical sep=<dimension>`

we set *the spacing between the plots in the horizontal and vertical direction, respectively. If you thus want them to be glued together you should set them both to a length of 0pt.*

**2. X label**

With

- `group/x descriptions at=all|edge top|edge bottom`
- `group/y descriptions at=all|edge left|edge right`

we can set the position of the x and y label. *These are simply a short hand for using both xticklabels at and xlabels at simultaneously.* The problem is that we placed the titles above and the legend below. So we can only put the x label to the right of each x axes. To do that we first set `group/group name={<name>}` in the `groupplot` environment. After that we *can refer the plots*:

```
% bar chart 1
\node[xshift=.75cm, yshift=-.2cm] at (myResults c1r1.south east) {x-Label};
% bar chart 2
\node[xshift=.75cm, yshift=-.2cm] at (myResults c2r1.south east) {x-Label};
```

**3. Title**

To set the titles we can add the option `title={<title>}` to each `\nextgroupplot`.

**Complete Code:**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group name=myResults, group size=2 by 1, horizontal sep=2.5cm},width=12cm,height=8cm, ylabel = {y}]
        \nextgroupplot[
            title={Title 1},
            %legend style={at={(mygroup.south)},anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            symbolic x coords={Precision,Recall,F1-Score,Accuracy},
            major tick length=0cm,
            xtick=data,
            ymin=50.0,
            enlarge x limits=0.2,
            enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.2},
            nodes near coords,
            ybar,
            every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
            bar width = 8pt
        ]

        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,86.6) (Recall,86.0) (F1-Score,86.3) (Accuracy,98.4)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,87.6) (Recall,86.2) (F1-Score,86.5) (Accuracy,97.5)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,85.9) (Recall,86.3) (F1-Score,86.1) (Accuracy,98.6)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,87.1) (Recall,86.8) (F1-Score,87.0) (Accuracy,99.2)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,85.5) (Recall,82.8) (F1-Score,83.7) (Accuracy,97.4)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,77.9) (Recall,77.7) (F1-Score,75.9) (Accuracy,87.8)};
        %\legend{KNN,Neural Networks,Decision Tree,Random Forest,SVM,Naive Bayes}

        \nextgroupplot[
            title={Title 2},
            legend style={at={(-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/group/horizontal sep}/2,-0.1)},
                    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            symbolic x coords={Precision,Recall,F1-Score,Accuracy},
            major tick length=0cm,
            xtick=data,
            ymin=50.0,
            enlarge x limits=0.2,
            enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.2},
            nodes near coords,
            ybar,
            every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
            bar width = 8pt,
        ]

        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,86.6) (Recall,86.0) (F1-Score,86.3) (Accuracy,98.4)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,87.6) (Recall,86.2) (F1-Score,86.5) (Accuracy,97.5)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,85.9) (Recall,86.3) (F1-Score,86.1) (Accuracy,98.6)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,87.1) (Recall,86.8) (F1-Score,87.0) (Accuracy,99.2)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,85.5) (Recall,82.8) (F1-Score,83.7) (Accuracy,97.4)};
        \addplot coordinates {(Precision,77.9) (Recall,77.7) (F1-Score,75.9) (Accuracy,87.8)};
        



        \legend{KNN,Neural Networks,Decision Tree,Random Forest,SVM,Naive Bayes}
    \end{groupplot}

    % x axis label
    \node[xshift=.75cm, yshift=-.2cm] at (myResults c1r1.south east) {x-Label};
    \node[xshift=.75cm, yshift=-.2cm] at (myResults c2r1.south east) {x-Label};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Two bar charts side by side.]

Answer (score 1):

One more solution with a small bit more concise diagrams code:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group size=2 by 1,
            horizontal sep=2cm,  % <----- distance between plots
                    },
            width=12cm, height=8cm,
    major tick length=0cm,
    xtick=data,
    enlarge x limits=0.2,
    enlarge y limits={upper,value=0.2},
    ybar,
    ymin=60.0,
    symbolic x coords={Precision,Recall,F1-Score,Accuracy},
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west},
%
    legend style={at={(-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/group/horizontal sep}/2,-0.1)},
                  anchor=north, legend columns=-1,
                  /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=1em}},            
                      ]
\nextgroupplot[
    bar width = 9pt,
    title = {Title 1},
    ylabel= $y$
              ]
\addplot coordinates {(Precision,86.6) (Recall,86.0) (F1-Score,86.3) (Accuracy,98.4)};
\addplot coordinates {(Precision,87.6) (Recall,86.2) (F1-Score,86.5) (Accuracy,97.5)};
\addplot coordinates {(Precision,85.9) (Recall,86.3) (F1-Score,86.1) (Accuracy,98.6)};
\addplot coordinates {(Precision,87.1) (Recall,86.8) (F1-Score,87.0) (Accuracy,99.2)};
\addplot coordinates {(Precision,85.5) (Recall,82.8) (F1-Score,83.7) (Accuracy,97.4)};
\addplot coordinates {(Precision,77.9) (Recall,77.7) (F1-Score,75.9) (Accuracy,87.8)};

\nextgroupplot[
    bar width = 9pt,
    title = {Title 2},
    ylabel= $y$
            ]
\addplot coordinates {(Precision,86.6) (Recall,86.0) (F1-Score,86.3) (Accuracy,98.4)};
\addplot coordinates {(Precision,87.6) (Recall,86.2) (F1-Score,86.5) (Accuracy,97.5)};
\addplot coordinates {(Precision,85.9) (Recall,86.3) (F1-Score,86.1) (Accuracy,98.6)};
\addplot coordinates {(Precision,87.1) (Recall,86.8) (F1-Score,87.0) (Accuracy,99.2)};
\addplot coordinates {(Precision,85.5) (Recall,82.8) (F1-Score,83.7) (Accuracy,97.4)};
\addplot coordinates {(Precision,77.9) (Recall,77.7) (F1-Score,75.9) (Accuracy,87.8)};

\legend{KNN,Neural Networks, Decision Tree,Random Forest,SVM,Naive Bayes}
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
In cases, when diagrams has different `x` and `y` axis, than their definitions should be moved from options of `groupplot` to options of `\nextgroupplot`.

Comment: Yes, a cleanup of the tex code was actually necessary. Good work.